# Erasing shiluv of A-donai H-avai

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names

Some sidurrim (prayer books) have the name of G-d "A-donai" and "Havai" mixed together like this:

י א ה ד ו נ ה י

Is one allowed to erase such a sequence? or is it forbidden like A-donai or Havai individually?

Comment: Imo, it would be good to expand this question to "what kabbalistic arrangements of Hashem's name can be erased" or even more general "what is the sanctity status of the various Kabbalistic name arragements of Hashem's names"? There are a lot of these and it's a big subject.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://din.org.il/2021/06/07/%25D7%25AA%25D7%259C%25D7%2599%25D7%2595%25D7%259F-%25D7%25A2%25D7%259D-%25D7%25A9%25D7%259D-%25D7%2594/&ved=2ahUKEwjitMTkkYCEAxUHTKQEHcHuCb8QFnoECA8QAQ&usg=AOvVaw2PQ-AT9smKQURIAymeTUGT according to this it has kedusha